# Visualising enzym kinetics (Michaelis Menten model)

Tags: equations, chemistry

I'd like to make a diagram like the one shown in the picture. I am able to write the first row using the `\ce{}` function, but don't know how to continue.

```
\ce{E + S <=>[k1][k_{-1}] & [ES] ->[k_2] P + E}
```

[image]

I'd be thankful for any help! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/406289/ which will give you the structure and harpoons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help fo `chemfig`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
E + S \arrow(a--b){<=>[$k_1$][$k_{-1}$]} {[ES]} \arrow{->[$k_2$]} P + E
\arrow(@a--c){<=>[*{0}$k_3$][*{0}$k_{-3}$]}[-90,1,,] {[EI]}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `chemarrow` package and several constructs it is possible to realize an image very similar that you have put.

[image]

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{chemarrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\[\setlength{\jot}{-10pt}\begin{aligned}
     \mathrm{E}&+\mathrm{S}\autorightleftharpoons{$k_1$}{$k_{-1}$}[\mathrm{ES}]\autorightarrow{$k_2$}{}\mathrm{P}+\mathrm{E}\\
     &+\mathrm{I}\\[8pt]
     &\mkern-26mu\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\autorightleftharpoons{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$k_3$}}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$k_{-3}$}}$}\\[10pt]
     &[\mathrm{EI}]
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

With `\scriptstyle` you wll have the differents `k` more small.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{chemarrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\[\setlength{\jot}{-10pt}\begin{aligned}
     \mathrm{E}&+\mathrm{S}\autorightleftharpoons{$\scriptstyle k_1$}{$\scriptstyle k_{-1}$}[\mathrm{ES}]\autorightarrow{$\scriptstyle k_2$}{}\mathrm{P}+\mathrm{E}\\
     &+\mathrm{I}\\[8pt]
     &\mkern-20mu\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\autorightleftharpoons{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\scriptstyle k_3$}}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\scriptstyle k_{-3}$}}$}\\[10pt]
     &[\mathrm{EI}]
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

Here there is an example:

[image]